# serialWrite issue in C# button click event

Tags: c#, delegates, serial-port

I am trying to resolve a serial communication issue in C# to an Arduino. I want to send two (or more separate messages to the Arduino using serial.Write().  The Arduino receives the first one. But, not the second. The Arduino receives the first string and fires a "CONNECTED" message back without any problems. C# picks up "CONNECTED" using a dataReceived event.  Then, the second message is never received by Arduino. I know the Arduino code works because it works fine using the serial monitor. I figured out how use a delegate to get the received data back to the UI. I then tried using a delegate to click the same button again and use switch/case to toggle the serialWrite messages.  But, I think delegates only work with methods and not events.  I also tried an eventHandler().  But, I couldn't find enough examples really understand it. I also tried sending and receiving back and forth in the click event, which also didn't work. I did discover that I can fire the second message from a different button click event and it  makes it to the Arduino.  There's probably a better way to do what I'm trying to do here.  But, I haven't found one yet...Please help.

C# code:

```
   private void INIT_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        code_window.Items.Clear();
        serialPort.WriteLine("100");  // This gets received
        Task.Delay(1000);
        serialPort.WriteLine("X1234Y23423Z134");  // This doesn't      
    }

    private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string incoming_string = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        if (incoming_string.StartsWith("X"))
        {
            string X_value = incoming_string.Substring(1, incoming_string.IndexOf("Y") - 1);
            set_X_position(X_value);  //  runs with a delegate
        }
        else
        {
            set_text(incoming_string);  // set_text runs with delegate
        }
    }
    
    private void set_text(string text)
    {   
        //  All of this works great  
        //  A different method invokes the second line to a different textbox
        if (this.code_window.InvokeRequired)
        {
            update_from_Arduino update = new update_from_Arduino(set_text);
            this.Invoke(update, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.code_window.Items.Add(text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe this `await Task.Delay(1000);` ??

Comment: try `Thread.Sleep(1000);` instead of `Task.Delay`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to exclude the "100" write.  I realized that it wasn't required and the Arduino could still respond twice after receiving one incoming string.